# Pure CSS Modal in SASS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I'm trying to recreate this pure CSS modal in SASS for my Rails app:

http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg

Here is my SASS

```
//
// Variables
// ----------------------

$gray: #333
$gray-light: #aaa
$gray-lighter: #eee
$space: 40px
$blue: #428bca
$blue-dark: darken($blue, 5%)

// Mixin for transition/transform
=translate($x, $y) 
  -webkit-transform: translate($x, $y)
  -ms-transform: translate($x, $y)
  transform: translate($x, $y)

=transition($transition) 
  -webkit-transition: $transition
  transition: $transition

=transition-transform($transition) 
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform $transition
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform $transition
  -o-transition: -o-transform $transition
  transition: transform $transition



//
// Btn 
// ----------------------

.mbtn
  background: $blue
  border: $blue-dark solid 1px
  border-radius: 3px
  color: #fff
  display: inline-block
  font-size: 14px
  padding: 8px 15px
  text-decoration: none
  text-align: center
  min-width: 60px
  position: relative
  transition: color .1s ease
  margin-bottom: 10px
  /* top: 40em;*/

  &:hover
    background: $blue-dark


  &.mbtn-big
    font-size: 18px
    padding: 15px 20px
    min-width: 100px



.mbtn-close
  color: $gray-light
  font-size: 30px
  text-decoration: none
  position: absolute 
  right: 5px 
  top: 0

  &:hover
    color: darken($gray-light, 10%)




//
// Modal
// ----------------------

.modal


  // This is modal bg
  &:before
    content: ""
    display: none
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6)
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    right: 0
    bottom: 0
    z-index: 10


  &:target

    // Active animate in modal
    &:before
      display: block

    .modal-dialog
      +translate(0, 0)
      top: 20%

// Modal Dialog
// ----------------------

.modal-dialog
  background: #fefefe
  //border: $gray solid 1px
  border-radius: 5px
  margin-left: -200px
  position: fixed
  left: 50%
  top: -100%  
  z-index: 11 
  width: 360px
  +translate(0, -500%)
  +transition-transform("3s, ease-out")


.modal-body
  padding: $space/2


.modal-header,
.modal-footer
  padding: $space/4 $space/2


.modal-header
  //border-bottom: $gray-lighter solid 1px

  h2
    font-size: 20px

.modal-footer
  //border-top: $gray-lighter solid 1px
  text-align: right


/*ADDED TO STOP SCROLLING TO TOP*/
#close 
  display: none
```

Here is my HAML:

```
        %a.mbtn.mbtn-big{:href => "#modal-one"} Modal!
        #modal-one.modal{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
            .modal-dialog
            .modal-header
                %h2 Modal in CSS?
                %a.mbtn-close{"aria-hidden" => "true", :href => "#close"} ×
                / CHANGED TO "#close"
            .modal-body
                %p One modal example here! :D
            .modal-footer
                %a.mbtn{:href => "#close"} Nice!
                / CHANGED TO "#close"
```

For some reason `"aria-hidden" => "true"` is not being honored and the modal is visible in addition to button when the page loads. I have included an image below:

[image]

When I click the modal button the page darkens and I am unable to click any elements on the page. All help is appreciated, I'm not sure where I went wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: The modal background is covering the whole page...of course you can't click through.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I do not understand why the modal content is visible on page load.

Comment: I don't see any code here that would indicate that it *should* be hidden.  If this is supposed to be a native browser feature, you have *waaay* too much code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you click the link at the top of my question you will see that it is hidden. I believe `aria-hidden` should be accomplishing this.

Comment: Why do you believe that `aria-hidden` should do any such thing?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden unless I am misunderstanding something

Comment: You linked right to your answer:  "It is recommended that authors key visibility of elements off this attribute, rather than change visibility and separately have to remember to update this property. CSS 2 provides a way to select on attribute values ([CSS]). The following CSS declaration makes content visible unless the aria-hidden attribute is true; scripts need only update the value of this attribute to change visibility: `[aria-hidden="true"] { visibility: hidden; }`"

Comment: That doesn't quite clarify my question, if you look at the example I based my code off of it works as expected. I have not actually changed any code, simply changed the formatting from LESS to SASS and HTML to HAML